# Yocto Linux kernel : How to build .NET core framework into my Linux image?

Tags: .net, sdk, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I build Linux distribution for my embedded board using **Yocto** project SUMO branch.

I want to add **.NET core framework 3.0 or later version** to my image and my SDK toolchain.

What should I do please ?